# Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory when starting rails container on Windows 10 host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, bundler

I am having trouble with a rails container in a docker-compose network. I have not touched it in a few months, and when I attempted to start it this week it fails.

When I attempt to start the container with `docker-compose up service` the startup fails with:

```
service_1  | Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
support_portal_service_1 exited with code 10
```

Both files are present, the host is a Windows 10 machine.

`Bundle install` completes succesfully:

```
Bundle complete! 19 Gemfile dependencies, 83 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `/usr/local/bundle`
```

What I have tried:

- Added ruby and ruby-all-dev to apt-get install in case missing requirements were the issue
- Changed `ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile` to `COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile`
- Tried commenting out `Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock`
- Ran `bundle install` on the Windows 10 host
- Rebuild the container without cache
- Insuring docker has access to the drive/directory

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs default-libmysqlclient-dev ruby ruby-all-dev
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
#COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
WORKDIR /app
RUN bundle install
ADD . /app
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  # Structured database
  sqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - sql:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=web
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${PORTAL_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${PORTAL_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  # Application server
  service:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - "3000"
    depends_on:
      - sqldb

  # Front end proxy
  web:
    image: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-web
    depends_on:
      - service
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "144:144"

# Persistence
volumes:
  sql:
```

Comment: Delete the `volumes:` section of your `docker-compose.yml` file.  It's hiding almost everything your `Dockerfile` does, and is a likely cause of this issue.  (And _do_ `COPY` the `Gemfile.lock` file.)

Comment: That worked!! Any idea why the volume section stopped working in the last few months?

Comment: You changed something in your host environment; you're trying to run this on a different system; ???

Comment: @DavidMaze please post that comment as an answer to this question so that we can upvote..